# How to manipulate text with awk?

Tags: text, awk, grep, text-manipulation

How would I be able to manipulate the output text of grep.

Right now I am using the command:

```
grep -i "<url>" $file  >> ./txtFiles/$file.txt
```

This would output something like this:

```
<url>http://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/chicken_curry_salad/</url>
```

and then the next text will go to the next line.

How would I be able to get rid of the `<url>` and `</url>` and stop it from going to the next line at the end.

Comment: get rid of the what? maybe you want to remove the new line character, in that case pipe it in tr "\n" " "

Answer (score 2):

```sh
sed '/<\/*url>/!d;s///g'
```

- `<\/*url>` matches both start and end tag
- Delete lines that don't have this
- Then remove all cases of this pattern

With your example, it might look like this

```sh
sed '/<\/*url>/!d;s///g' $file >> ./txtFiles/$file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks this works.  One last thing though, it still goes to the next line after the url.  Do you know how I would be able to get rid of this so that the next text would be able to just follow right after.

Comment: or maybe it is how I am adding the next line.  I am using printf, so I am assuming that that is what is causing it to go the next line for the following text.  Is there something else I should be using to append the text at the end of the line, instead of at a new line?

Answer (score 0):

Single commands:

```
sed -in '/<url>/ { s|<url>\(.*\)</url>|\1| ; p ; }' INPUT > OUTPUT
```

Or with awk:

```
awk -F "</?url>" '/<url>/ { print $2 }' INPUT > OUTPUT
```

*Note*: both might give you invalid output if more than one `<url>...</url>` patterns are occurring on a single line. The `sed` version might fail if the `<url>...</url>` contains any pipe (`|`) character.